# Can I use SVG for app icon and splash screen? for both ios and android

Tags: android, ios, icons, splash-screen

I was wondering if it's allowed to use a large SVG images like `icon.svg` & `splash.svg`, and let the OS scale it as it wishes to the corresponding size?

And if yes, for which OS?

And would this be considered a bad practice?

Answer (score 5):

On iOS the answer is no, you can't use SVG images for either the icon or the splash screen. You need to use a PNG for both.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, not natively supported by android. Android Visual Studio allows converting to SVG to PNG at design time.

Third party libraries for Android which allow using svg graphics at run-time:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/svg-android/downloads

https://code.google.com/archive/p/svg-android-2/

Few years ago I tried them, but there weren't quite accurate. Maybe have been fixed by now.